# how do I make devices show up in Opendaylight topology?

Tags: opendaylight, openvswitch

I am setting up an `SDN` using `Open vSwitch` and `OpenDaylight`.

I have two machines with Ubuntu and I am using `KVM` to simulate two devices (for now).

I've reached the point where I have an `openflow` switch and three hosts show up in the `OpenDaylight Dlux` network topology - the two virtual devices and the one machine; the other machine is the one that has `ovs` and `odl`.

I have two other devices in the network which don't show up in the topology. I can ping these devices from each machine. If these devices do not 'speak' `openflow`, is it possible to get them to show up in the network topology? and if this is possible - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switches in your topology show up because they are connected as
openflow devices. "hosts" that connect to each switch will show up
when they send traffic that traverses the switches. Those are the
only way, that I know, which devices will show up in the topology.

Comment: aha! yes, when I pinged from one of the virtual devices to the real ones, then the real devices showed up in the network topology. thanks for the explanation!